# siunitx: What is the correct way to output mean and standard deviation as "M (SD)" in an S-column?

Tags: siunitx, r

I am trying to use [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) in a psychology results table to line up decimals, and the table looks like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean (SD)} \\
    \hline
    A & B \\
    \hline
    .45 (.23) & .78 (.11) \\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This does not follow the short form uncertainty that `siunitx` uses, rather it gives the full standard deviation value (as is usual in psychology).

My question is how can I make `siunitx` output to the format `M (SD)` whilst providing `SD` with an actual standard deviation value in the code (such as .11)? I cannot use the short uncertainty format of `siunitx` because the input is from R code (using knitr) that returns the real standard deviation value, e.g. `\Sexpr{sd(some.numbers)}`.

Edit: I have tried `separate-uncertainty` but this seems to force an output of `M ± SD` and I would like to use `M (SD)`.

Comment: Perhaps put them in two columns, with a header that spans them?

Comment: @ChrisS I'm assuming that's 'cheating' (it's what I'd do, I suspect, but ...)

Comment: @JosephWright No, just trying to avoid a mass of extra work. I guess if that's the only way then I will have to change my tables.

Answer (score 1):

The formats parsed by `siunitx` are `1.23(4)` and `1.23 \pm 0.04`, and no others. Thus to achieve the desired effect some parsing has to be done separately. One approach is to grab the cell contents, alter the formatting and use the `\tablenum` command to do the alignment

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\converter\ignorespaces#1(#2){%
  \begingroup\tablenum[table-format = 1.2]{#1}\endgroup\space
  (\tablenum[table-format = 1.2]{#2})}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\converter}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}RR@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{Mean/SD} \\
    .45 (.23) & .78 (.11) \\
    0.2(.4) \\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that one seems to drop the decimal point from the SD, and it drops the space as well. My main interest is in getting the output exactly like "M (SD)" with the space and the full standard deviation (including the decimal point). Is there a way to change the output with `separate-uncertainty=true` turned on?

Comment: Is it possible to define some kind of new number type that is in the format `x (y)` ?

Comment: @drgibbon Adding an entirely new parser and output method to `siunitx` would be a major undertaking: internally the two steps are separate so the fact you want 'light' changes (alignment) doesn't mean that the change is trivial.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess this is not possible with `siunitx`, I will try to build it with separate columns for M and SD.

Comment: @drgibbon Did you see my edit?

Comment: I missed that, it looks quite good when the numbers stay sane, but my table is complicated, and the magnitude of the numbers changes within columns which mucks it up, and to fix it with that code is way out of my league. I have made a table using multiple columns and am going to post a new simpler (I hope) question about alignment.